# Can't delete files or folders using Cpanel filemanager

Tags: cpanel

i using CPanel . but every file after delete come back and with FileManager or ftp i cant chmod files! with PhpStorm or every ftp manager like CuteFtp problem exist !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are not able to delete the files , that states its a permission issue. The files that are owned by root user needs root use to change their permissions. make sure you are logging in with correct user that has permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Are You using root user in FTP?
If your FTP user is root and filemanager is not ... you can't alter files created by root.

Let me know that... I can help more.